# Output DOM with PHP

Tags: php, dom

I am used to using JSON and it seems a little different than DOM. There is a lot more than the 3 shown here:

```
<item>
  <ItemID>   </ItemID>
  <Title>  </Title>
</item>
<item>
  <ItemID>   </ItemID>
  <Title>  </Title>
</item>
<item>
  <ItemID>   </ItemID>
  <Title>  </Title>
</item>
```

This is the code that i am trying to use:

```
$response = curl_exec($connection);
curl_close($connection);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response);

$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName("item");

foreach($items as $mydata) {
    $id = $mydata->getElementsByTagName('ItemID');
    $title = $mydata->getElementsByTagName('Title');
echo $id;
echo $title;

}
```

mainly want to input those values into a DB. So something like:

```
$query .= "INSERT INTO `$table` "."(id, title) .........
```

I just can't seem to pull the ID and title out of the DOM.

Comment: I am not sure but tag names may be case sensitive. So, change `$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName("Item");`
 to `$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName("item");`

Comment: Thank you. I just wrote this quickly and that was a typo. not an issue in my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

First error is ignoring case-sensitivity. Tags should have the same cases as in provided xml.

Second error - `getElementsByTagName` returns `DOMNodeList`, which is a collection of elements. So, you either iterate over it or use `item()` method.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response);

$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName("item");  // not `Item`

foreach ($items as $mydata) {
    $id = $mydata->getElementsByTagName('ItemID');  // not `ItemId`
    $title = $mydata->getElementsByTagName('Title');

    // get first element of each collection
    echo $id->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $title->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: What would be the best route to save the info into a string? So say <Title>this title</Title>. Can I do $id = $mydata->getElementsByTagName('item')->item(0)->nodeValue;    This way I can just echo $id; ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $mydata->getElementsByTagName('ItemID')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

adding the ->item(0)->nodeValue; at the end did the trick! Thanks guys for helping me put it together!

Brian